# Android Surfaces Look alike Layout in pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, layout, surface, floating, slidingpanelayout

I am trying to design a layout in Android but I don't even know how to call it. It is somewhat similar to Android Surfaces I would say, but actually the old Google Maps Entry details are designed more like it and i would prefer to target sdks prior lollipop.

I want that a picture is shown on top of the screen.
Below is a Headline and below that is a List.

When i scroll down, the image shall be put into the background and the complete block of other elements should float above, taking roughly the half of the image heigth additionaly.

When i scroll down further the Headline element should be fixed on top of the screen, the image completele covered and the list should float under the Headline.

How does Google Maps achieve this? I am not even sure if it is a List that is displayed there below the image. Any ideas? The name of that design would suffice, any guides or tutorials are very appriciated.

I'm sure this needs a visual explanation: 
I want a design like the second screen shows it with a transition to the third screen.

Screenshots taken from Google Maps Android App.
[image: Three phases of display flow]

And here is the new Surface Layout from Android 5.0 but as i said, i would prefer to do it compatible to lower versions and besides this does not look like the fluent transparant change i aspire.

[image: Android L Surface visualization]

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Can't believe it was so hard to find. The magic keyword is **Sliding Panel**

To those who stumble upon this question, here is the most referenced library, but searching for Sliding Panel will help as well.
Sorry for bothering...

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel